# Checkstyle vs. nonJavadoc comments?

Tags: comments, javadoc, checkstyle

My company requires specific comment header blocks at the top of a file, prior to class definitions, and methods.

I'm using the `Regexp` in the config file to validate the file header comments. If there is a nonJavaDoc comment before a class or method, can I access the text?

My clunky solution is to get a CTOR_DEF or METHOD_DEF, then get the line number...then get the filecontents...find the line, then try to backup to the comment header.

Is there a way to get the text of nonJavaDoc comments in context? Thanks.

Comment: Checkstyle project is considering to add support for Comments validation , please support proposals at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/checkstyle/VEVFDsZKLzg

Answer (score 0):

Your *clunky* approach is the only viable one. I would suggest that you can use the method [FileContents.getCppComments()](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/FileContents.html#getCppComments%28%29) to get a map of all C++ comments in a file.

You may also find the method [FileContents.lineIsComment()](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/FileContents.html#lineIsComment%28int%29) is useful.